# ggplot issues (geom_line() shows no line, large numbers not displayed correctly on Y axis, sorting months by name on a plot X axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I need to make a few ggplots for my project but I have a lot of issues making them work. I don't know why is geom_line() not making a line, how do I fix the numbers displayed on the left (I'm working with large numbers) and is there any way to sort months without formatting them to numbers. Thanks.

[GGPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aRLJ.png)

[Data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUGu.png)

```
day_wise %>% 
select(Date,Confirmed,Recovered,Deaths) %>% mutate(AsDate=as.Date(Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% mutate(Month=format(AsDate,format="%B")) %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise("Infected"=sum(Confirmed),Recovered=sum(Recovered),Deaths=sum(Deaths)) %>% arrange(Recovered)
```

```
day_wise %>% 
select(Date,Confirmed,Recovered,Deaths) %>% mutate(AsDate=as.Date(Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% mutate(Month=format(AsDate,format="%B")) %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise("Infected"=sum(Confirmed),Recovered=sum(Recovered),Deaths=sum(Deaths)) %>% arrange(Recovered)
```

DPUT

```
structure(list(Date = c("2020-01-22", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-24", 
"2020-01-25", "2020-01-26", "2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", 
"2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", 
"2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-07", "2020-02-08", 
"2020-02-09", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", 
"2020-02-14", "2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", 
"2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23", 
"2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", 
"2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", 
"2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", 
"2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", 
"2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", 
"2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", 
"2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", 
"2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", 
"2020-04-04", "2020-04-05", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", 
"2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", 
"2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", 
"2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", 
"2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", "2020-04-26", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", 
"2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", 
"2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", 
"2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", 
"2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", 
"2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", 
"2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", 
"2020-05-29", "2020-05-30", "2020-05-31", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", 
"2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-07", 
"2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", "2020-06-10", "2020-06-11", "2020-06-12", 
"2020-06-13", "2020-06-14", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-16", "2020-06-17", 
"2020-06-18", "2020-06-19", "2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-22", 
"2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", 
"2020-06-28", "2020-06-29", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-02", 
"2020-07-03", "2020-07-04", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", "2020-07-07", 
"2020-07-08", "2020-07-09", "2020-07-10", "2020-07-11", "2020-07-12", 
"2020-07-13", "2020-07-14", "2020-07-15", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-17", 
"2020-07-18", "2020-07-19", "2020-07-20", "2020-07-21", "2020-07-22", 
"2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-25", "2020-07-26", "2020-07-27"
), Confirmed = c(555L, 654L, 941L, 1434L, 2118L, 2927L, 5578L, 
6166L, 8234L, 9927L, 12038L, 16787L, 19887L, 23898L, 27643L, 
30802L, 34334L, 37068L, 40095L, 42633L, 44675L, 46561L, 60206L, 
66690L, 68765L, 70879L, 72815L, 74609L, 75030L, 75577L, 76206L, 
77967L, 78290L, 78854L, 79707L, 80670L, 82034L, 83411L, 85306L, 
87690L, 89664L, 92241L, 94540L, 97331L, 101274L, 105312L, 109266L, 
113166L, 118190L, 125853L, 131603L, 146008L, 157114L, 168260L, 
182919L, 198757L, 218343L, 246261L, 275869L, 308175L, 341585L, 
383750L, 424889L, 475706L, 538666L, 603066L, 670723L, 730300L, 
794939L, 871355L, 947569L, 1028968L, 1112123L, 1192586L, 1264304L, 
1336976L, 1413849L, 1497624L, 1584249L, 1671907L, 1748872L, 1845653L, 
1915247L, 1985174L, 2066003L, 2162715L, 2250439L, 2324396L, 2404919L, 
2478258L, 2553508L, 2630314L, 2719327L, 2806267L, 2891199L, 2964146L, 
3032850L, 3108149L, 3185195L, 3268876L, 3355922L, 3437608L, 3515244L, 
3591321L, 3671310L, 3761332L, 3850418L, 3941935L, 4027781L, 4104027L, 
4180268L, 4263867L, 4348619L, 4445724L, 4542073L, 4637485L, 4715994L, 
4804278L, 4900702L, 5003730L, 5110064L, 5216964L, 5322253L, 5417579L, 
5504542L, 5597064L, 5699664L, 5818978L, 5940145L, 6077978L, 6185530L, 
6280725L, 6401536L, 6520924L, 6647861L, 6778724L, 6914666L, 7026925L, 
7129150L, 7253492L, 7387517L, 7525631L, 7654725L, 7790735L, 7924156L, 
8043794L, 8185197L, 8327050L, 8466978L, 8647784L, 8805336L, 8933875L, 
9071733L, 9237071L, 9408254L, 9586141L, 9777487L, 9955597L, 10117227L, 
10275799L, 10449697L, 10667386L, 10875091L, 11078585L, 11272152L, 
11454847L, 11622190L, 11833034L, 12044836L, 12273063L, 12505640L, 
12721968L, 12914636L, 13107415L, 13328867L, 13559984L, 13812525L, 
14054563L, 14292198L, 14506845L, 14713623L, 14947078L, 15227725L, 
15510481L, 15791645L, 16047190L, 16251796L, 16480485L), Deaths = c(17L, 
18L, 26L, 42L, 56L, 82L, 131L, 133L, 171L, 213L, 259L, 362L, 
426L, 492L, 564L, 634L, 719L, 806L, 906L, 1013L, 1113L, 1118L, 
1371L, 1523L, 1666L, 1770L, 1868L, 2008L, 2123L, 2246L, 2250L, 
2457L, 2467L, 2627L, 2707L, 2767L, 2810L, 2867L, 2936L, 2990L, 
3079L, 3154L, 3249L, 3342L, 3454L, 3553L, 3797L, 3981L, 4260L, 
4604L, 4909L, 5406L, 5823L, 6464L, 7144L, 7948L, 8845L, 9951L, 
11429L, 13134L, 14831L, 16748L, 19016L, 21793L, 24800L, 28318L, 
31997L, 35470L, 39634L, 44478L, 50029L, 56334L, 62319L, 68160L, 
73181L, 79013L, 86915L, 93650L, 101279L, 108551L, 114620L, 120351L, 
126098L, 132996L, 141308L, 148591L, 157481L, 163952L, 168522L, 
173965L, 181122L, 187877L, 194727L, 201401L, 206979L, 210862L, 
215511L, 221974L, 228742L, 234704L, 239881L, 245206L, 248659L, 
252787L, 258658L, 265327L, 270736L, 276304L, 280569L, 284135L, 
287608L, 293155L, 298383L, 303651L, 308866L, 313037L, 316366L, 
319657L, 324441L, 329326L, 334112L, 339396L, 343385L, 346525L, 
347703L, 351906L, 357119L, 361820L, 366562L, 370718L, 373606L, 
376674L, 381497L, 387069L, 392218L, 396994L, 400875L, 403617L, 
407314L, 412236L, 417441L, 422215L, 426512L, 430750L, 434124L, 
437549L, 444416L, 449671L, 454700L, 460973L, 465222L, 469185L, 
472756L, 478067L, 483328L, 489955L, 494782L, 499268L, 502357L, 
506078L, 511210L, 516221L, 521341L, 526336L, 530705L, 534150L, 
537947L, 544054L, 549373L, 554831L, 560142L, 565039L, 568993L, 
572808L, 578468L, 583961L, 589760L, 596503L, 602130L, 606159L, 
610319L, 616557L, 623540L, 633506L, 639650L, 644517L, 648621L, 
654036L), Recovered = c(28L, 30L, 36L, 39L, 52L, 61L, 107L, 125L, 
141L, 219L, 281L, 459L, 604L, 821L, 1071L, 1418L, 1903L, 2470L, 
3057L, 3714L, 4417L, 4849L, 5930L, 7613L, 8902L, 10319L, 11951L, 
13693L, 15394L, 17369L, 17966L, 21849L, 22304L, 24047L, 26652L, 
29077L, 31919L, 35306L, 38314L, 41208L, 44085L, 46681L, 49619L, 
52237L, 54270L, 56760L, 59092L, 60891L, 62802L, 65113L, 66434L, 
68359L, 70729L, 74139L, 76192L, 78944L, 81427L, 83064L, 85509L, 
89775L, 95990L, 96456L, 105997L, 111445L, 119804L, 128508L, 136800L, 
146261L, 161707L, 174074L, 189434L, 206052L, 221060L, 241072L, 
254477L, 270812L, 293665L, 322017L, 346349L, 367477L, 392991L, 
411864L, 438395L, 463014L, 498925L, 529015L, 554287L, 577789L, 
608557L, 629862L, 664043L, 693207L, 721689L, 771329L, 798239L, 
825969L, 852382L, 884680L, 925752L, 989616L, 1026501L, 1066362L, 
1097577L, 1130526L, 1166155L, 1210894L, 1249311L, 1284849L, 1337367L, 
1370108L, 1416204L, 1452191L, 1506905L, 1545712L, 1592880L, 1648546L, 
1688699L, 1740909L, 1792256L, 1850441L, 1900768L, 2008541L, 2062802L, 
2117555L, 2180605L, 2235118L, 2297613L, 2363746L, 2440127L, 2509981L, 
2585589L, 2639599L, 2743083L, 2821430L, 2890776L, 2959037L, 3030214L, 
3084718L, 3235640L, 3317121L, 3395154L, 3480121L, 3558933L, 3644048L, 
3714006L, 3793406L, 3890800L, 4008201L, 4088826L, 4183298L, 4298603L, 
4366875L, 4458093L, 4561696L, 4677005L, 4769458L, 4875774L, 4981808L, 
5070592L, 5164494L, 5281459L, 5397083L, 5681477L, 5790942L, 5986375L, 
6105546L, 6228768L, 6373513L, 6531016L, 6665237L, 6804254L, 6929711L, 
7041174L, 7181139L, 7322897L, 7482320L, 7634241L, 7793760L, 7944550L, 
8032235L, 8190777L, 8364986L, 8541255L, 8710969L, 8939705L, 9158743L, 
9293464L, 9468087L), Active = c(510L, 606L, 879L, 1353L, 2010L, 
2784L, 5340L, 5908L, 7922L, 9495L, 11498L, 15966L, 18857L, 22585L, 
26008L, 28750L, 31712L, 33792L, 36132L, 37906L, 39145L, 40594L, 
52905L, 57554L, 58197L, 58790L, 58996L, 58908L, 57513L, 55962L, 
55990L, 53661L, 53519L, 52180L, 50348L, 48826L, 47305L, 45238L, 
44056L, 43492L, 42500L, 42406L, 41672L, 41752L, 43550L, 44999L, 
46377L, 48294L, 51128L, 56136L, 60260L, 72243L, 80562L, 87657L, 
99583L, 111865L, 128071L, 153246L, 178931L, 205266L, 230764L, 
270546L, 299876L, 342468L, 394062L, 446240L, 501926L, 548569L, 
593598L, 652803L, 708106L, 766582L, 828744L, 883354L, 936646L, 
987151L, 1033269L, 1081957L, 1136621L, 1195879L, 1241261L, 1313438L, 
1350754L, 1389164L, 1425770L, 1485109L, 1538671L, 1582655L, 1627840L, 
1674431L, 1708343L, 1749230L, 1802911L, 1833537L, 1885981L, 1927315L, 
1964957L, 2001495L, 2030701L, 2044556L, 2089540L, 2126040L, 2169008L, 
2208008L, 2246497L, 2285111L, 2330371L, 2380782L, 2409845L, 2449784L, 
2476456L, 2518521L, 2543331L, 2596361L, 2640327L, 2675902L, 2710929L, 
2743712L, 2784005L, 2823963L, 2875184L, 2869027L, 2916066L, 2953499L, 
2976234L, 3010040L, 3044932L, 3093412L, 3133456L, 3197279L, 3226335L, 
3264452L, 3276956L, 3312425L, 3364867L, 3422693L, 3483577L, 3538590L, 
3486196L, 3524135L, 3574922L, 3623295L, 3669280L, 3715937L, 3776026L, 
3812839L, 3849981L, 3869178L, 3923452L, 4003513L, 4041511L, 4097815L, 
4140884L, 4197308L, 4247921L, 4326728L, 4406931L, 4474521L, 4544278L, 
4605227L, 4657028L, 4754082L, 4672273L, 4761307L, 4755072L, 4815151L, 
4855475L, 4915467L, 4964447L, 5052995L, 5141244L, 5227218L, 5304469L, 
5353468L, 5427502L, 5493703L, 5588524L, 5664300L, 5745518L, 5868451L, 
5912527L, 5965535L, 6062930L, 6166006L, 6212290L, 6243930L, 6309711L, 
6358362L), New.cases = c(0L, 99L, 287L, 493L, 684L, 809L, 2651L, 
588L, 2068L, 1693L, 2111L, 4749L, 3100L, 4011L, 3745L, 3159L, 
3532L, 2734L, 3027L, 2538L, 2042L, 1886L, 13645L, 6484L, 2075L, 
2114L, 1936L, 1794L, 421L, 547L, 629L, 1761L, 323L, 564L, 853L, 
963L, 1364L, 1377L, 1895L, 2384L, 1974L, 2577L, 2299L, 2791L, 
3943L, 4038L, 3954L, 3900L, 5024L, 7663L, 5750L, 14405L, 11106L, 
11146L, 14659L, 15838L, 19586L, 27918L, 29608L, 32306L, 33410L, 
42165L, 41154L, 50817L, 62960L, 64400L, 67657L, 59577L, 64639L, 
76416L, 76214L, 81399L, 83155L, 80463L, 71718L, 72672L, 76873L, 
83775L, 86625L, 87658L, 76965L, 96802L, 69594L, 69927L, 80829L, 
96712L, 87724L, 73958L, 80523L, 73339L, 75250L, 78994L, 89013L, 
96974L, 84932L, 72948L, 68704L, 75404L, 79558L, 83681L, 87046L, 
81853L, 77636L, 76078L, 79989L, 90022L, 90669L, 92997L, 85846L, 
76255L, 76298L, 83619L, 84917L, 97106L, 96349L, 95412L, 78509L, 
88284L, 96633L, 103028L, 106438L, 106900L, 105289L, 95326L, 87335L, 
92742L, 102600L, 119314L, 121167L, 137833L, 107552L, 95195L, 
121577L, 119389L, 126937L, 130863L, 135942L, 112259L, 102225L, 
124342L, 134025L, 138114L, 129094L, 136010L, 133421L, 119638L, 
141403L, 141853L, 139928L, 180954L, 157552L, 128539L, 137858L, 
165338L, 171183L, 177887L, 191346L, 178110L, 162349L, 158572L, 
173898L, 217689L, 207705L, 203495L, 193567L, 182695L, 167343L, 
210844L, 211802L, 228227L, 232577L, 216328L, 192668L, 192779L, 
221452L, 231122L, 252544L, 242038L, 237635L, 214647L, 206778L, 
233565L, 280647L, 282756L, 281164L, 255545L, 204606L, 228693L
), New.deaths = c(0L, 1L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 26L, 49L, 2L, 38L, 42L, 
46L, 103L, 64L, 66L, 72L, 70L, 85L, 87L, 100L, 107L, 100L, 5L, 
253L, 152L, 143L, 104L, 98L, 140L, 115L, 123L, 4L, 207L, 10L, 
160L, 80L, 60L, 43L, 57L, 69L, 54L, 89L, 75L, 95L, 93L, 112L, 
99L, 244L, 184L, 279L, 344L, 305L, 497L, 417L, 641L, 680L, 804L, 
897L, 1106L, 1478L, 1705L, 1697L, 1917L, 2268L, 2777L, 3007L, 
3518L, 3679L, 3473L, 4164L, 4844L, 5551L, 6305L, 5985L, 5841L, 
5021L, 5832L, 7902L, 6735L, 7629L, 7272L, 6069L, 5731L, 5747L, 
6898L, 8312L, 7283L, 8890L, 6471L, 4570L, 5443L, 7157L, 6755L, 
6850L, 6674L, 5578L, 3883L, 4649L, 6463L, 6768L, 5962L, 5177L, 
5325L, 3453L, 4128L, 5871L, 6669L, 5409L, 5568L, 4265L, 3566L, 
3473L, 5547L, 5228L, 5268L, 5215L, 4171L, 3329L, 3291L, 4784L, 
4885L, 4786L, 5284L, 3989L, 3140L, 1178L, 4203L, 5213L, 4701L, 
4742L, 4156L, 2888L, 3068L, 4823L, 5572L, 5149L, 4776L, 3881L, 
2742L, 3697L, 4922L, 5205L, 4774L, 4297L, 4238L, 3374L, 3425L, 
6867L, 5255L, 5029L, 6273L, 4249L, 3963L, 3571L, 5311L, 5261L, 
6627L, 4827L, 4486L, 3089L, 3721L, 5132L, 5011L, 5120L, 4995L, 
4369L, 3445L, 3797L, 6107L, 5319L, 5458L, 5311L, 4897L, 3954L, 
3815L, 5660L, 5493L, 5799L, 6743L, 5627L, 4029L, 4160L, 6238L, 
6983L, 9966L, 6144L, 4867L, 4104L, 5415L), New.recovered = c(0L, 
2L, 6L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 46L, 18L, 16L, 78L, 62L, 178L, 145L, 217L, 
250L, 347L, 485L, 567L, 587L, 657L, 703L, 432L, 1081L, 1683L, 
1289L, 1417L, 1632L, 1742L, 1701L, 1975L, 597L, 3883L, 455L, 
1743L, 2605L, 2425L, 2842L, 3387L, 3008L, 2894L, 2877L, 2596L, 
2938L, 2618L, 2033L, 2490L, 2332L, 1799L, 1911L, 2311L, 1321L, 
1925L, 2370L, 3410L, 2053L, 2752L, 2483L, 1637L, 2445L, 4266L, 
6215L, 466L, 9541L, 5448L, 8359L, 8704L, 8292L, 9461L, 15446L, 
12367L, 15360L, 16618L, 15008L, 20012L, 13405L, 16335L, 22853L, 
28352L, 24332L, 21128L, 25514L, 18873L, 26531L, 24619L, 35911L, 
30090L, 25272L, 23502L, 30768L, 21305L, 34181L, 29164L, 28482L, 
49640L, 26910L, 27730L, 26413L, 32298L, 41072L, 63864L, 36885L, 
39861L, 31215L, 32949L, 35629L, 44739L, 38417L, 35538L, 52518L, 
32741L, 46096L, 35987L, 54714L, 38807L, 47168L, 55666L, 40153L, 
52210L, 51347L, 58185L, 50327L, 107773L, 54261L, 54753L, 63050L, 
54513L, 62495L, 66133L, 76381L, 69854L, 75608L, 54010L, 103484L, 
78347L, 69346L, 68261L, 71177L, 54504L, 150922L, 81481L, 78033L, 
84967L, 78812L, 85115L, 69958L, 79400L, 97394L, 117401L, 80625L, 
94472L, 115305L, 68272L, 91218L, 103603L, 115309L, 92453L, 106316L, 
106034L, 88784L, 93902L, 116965L, 115624L, 284394L, 109465L, 
195433L, 119171L, 123222L, 144745L, 157503L, 134221L, 139017L, 
125457L, 111463L, 139965L, 141758L, 159423L, 151921L, 159519L, 
150790L, 87685L, 158542L, 174209L, 176269L, 169714L, 228736L, 
219038L, 134721L, 174623L), Deaths...100.Cases = c(3.06, 2.75, 
2.76, 2.93, 2.64, 2.8, 2.35, 2.16, 2.08, 2.15, 2.15, 2.16, 2.14, 
2.06, 2.04, 2.06, 2.09, 2.17, 2.26, 2.38, 2.49, 2.4, 2.28, 2.28, 
2.42, 2.5, 2.57, 2.69, 2.83, 2.97, 2.95, 3.15, 3.15, 3.33, 3.4, 
3.43, 3.43, 3.44, 3.44, 3.41, 3.43, 3.42, 3.44, 3.43, 3.41, 3.37, 
3.48, 3.52, 3.6, 3.66, 3.73, 3.7, 3.71, 3.84, 3.91, 4, 4.05, 
4.04, 4.14, 4.26, 4.34, 4.36, 4.48, 4.58, 4.6, 4.7, 4.77, 4.86, 
4.99, 5.1, 5.28, 5.47, 5.6, 5.72, 5.79, 5.91, 6.15, 6.25, 6.39, 
6.49, 6.55, 6.52, 6.58, 6.7, 6.84, 6.87, 7, 7.05, 7.01, 7.02, 
7.09, 7.14, 7.16, 7.18, 7.16, 7.11, 7.11, 7.14, 7.18, 7.18, 7.15, 
7.13, 7.07, 7.04, 7.05, 7.05, 7.03, 7.01, 6.97, 6.92, 6.88, 6.88, 
6.86, 6.83, 6.8, 6.75, 6.71, 6.65, 6.62, 6.58, 6.54, 6.51, 6.45, 
6.4, 6.32, 6.29, 6.27, 6.22, 6.17, 6.1, 6.04, 6, 5.96, 5.94, 
5.9, 5.86, 5.8, 5.74, 5.71, 5.68, 5.65, 5.61, 5.57, 5.53, 5.48, 
5.44, 5.43, 5.4, 5.37, 5.33, 5.28, 5.25, 5.21, 5.18, 5.14, 5.11, 
5.06, 5.01, 4.97, 4.92, 4.89, 4.84, 4.79, 4.75, 4.71, 4.66, 4.63, 
4.6, 4.56, 4.52, 4.48, 4.44, 4.41, 4.37, 4.34, 4.31, 4.27, 4.24, 
4.21, 4.18, 4.15, 4.12, 4.09, 4.08, 4.05, 4.02, 3.99, 3.97), 
    Recovered...100.Cases = c(5.05, 4.59, 3.83, 2.72, 2.46, 2.08, 
    1.92, 2.03, 1.71, 2.21, 2.33, 2.73, 3.04, 3.44, 3.87, 4.6, 
    5.54, 6.66, 7.62, 8.71, 9.89, 10.41, 9.85, 11.42, 12.95, 
    14.56, 16.41, 18.35, 20.52, 22.98, 23.58, 28.02, 28.49, 30.5, 
    33.44, 36.04, 38.91, 42.33, 44.91, 46.99, 49.17, 50.61, 52.48, 
    53.67, 53.59, 53.9, 54.08, 53.81, 53.14, 51.74, 50.48, 46.82, 
    45.02, 44.06, 41.65, 39.72, 37.29, 33.73, 31, 29.13, 28.1, 
    25.14, 24.95, 23.43, 22.24, 21.31, 20.4, 20.03, 20.34, 19.98, 
    19.99, 20.03, 19.88, 20.21, 20.13, 20.26, 20.77, 21.5, 21.86, 
    21.98, 22.47, 22.32, 22.89, 23.32, 24.15, 24.46, 24.63, 24.86, 
    25.3, 25.42, 26.01, 26.35, 26.54, 27.49, 27.61, 27.87, 28.1, 
    28.46, 29.06, 30.27, 30.59, 31.02, 31.22, 31.48, 31.76, 32.19, 
    32.45, 32.59, 33.2, 33.38, 33.88, 34.06, 34.65, 34.77, 35.07, 
    35.55, 35.81, 36.24, 36.57, 36.98, 37.2, 38.5, 38.76, 39.09, 
    39.61, 39.93, 40.31, 40.62, 41.08, 41.3, 41.8, 42.03, 42.85, 
    43.27, 43.48, 43.65, 43.82, 43.9, 45.39, 45.73, 45.96, 46.24, 
    46.49, 46.77, 46.87, 47.16, 47.53, 48.13, 48.29, 48.37, 48.82, 
    48.88, 49.14, 49.38, 49.71, 49.75, 49.87, 50.04, 50.12, 50.26, 
    50.54, 50.59, 52.24, 52.27, 53.11, 53.3, 53.59, 53.86, 54.22, 
    54.31, 54.41, 54.47, 54.52, 54.79, 54.94, 55.18, 55.27, 55.45, 
    55.59, 55.37, 55.67, 55.96, 56.09, 56.16, 56.61, 57.07, 57.18, 
    57.45), Deaths...100.Recovered = c(60.71, 60, 72.22, 107.69, 
    107.69, 134.43, 122.43, 106.4, 121.28, 97.26, 92.17, 78.87, 
    70.53, 59.93, 52.66, 44.71, 37.78, 32.63, 29.64, 27.28, 25.2, 
    23.06, 23.12, 20.01, 18.71, 17.15, 15.63, 14.66, 13.79, 12.93, 
    12.52, 11.25, 11.06, 10.92, 10.16, 9.52, 8.8, 8.12, 7.66, 
    7.26, 6.98, 6.76, 6.55, 6.4, 6.36, 6.26, 6.43, 6.54, 6.78, 
    7.07, 7.39, 7.91, 8.23, 8.72, 9.38, 10.07, 10.86, 11.98, 
    13.37, 14.63, 15.45, 17.36, 17.94, 19.55, 20.7, 22.04, 23.39, 
    24.25, 24.51, 25.55, 26.41, 27.34, 28.19, 28.27, 28.76, 29.18, 
    29.6, 29.08, 29.24, 29.54, 29.17, 29.22, 28.76, 28.72, 28.32, 
    28.09, 28.41, 28.38, 27.69, 27.62, 27.28, 27.1, 26.98, 26.11, 
    25.93, 25.53, 25.28, 25.09, 24.71, 23.72, 23.37, 22.99, 22.66, 
    22.36, 22.18, 21.91, 21.67, 21.5, 20.98, 20.74, 20.31, 20.19, 
    19.8, 19.64, 19.39, 18.99, 18.73, 18.36, 18.1, 17.8, 17.58, 
    16.9, 16.65, 16.36, 15.95, 15.74, 15.54, 15.31, 15.02, 14.77, 
    14.45, 14.27, 13.91, 13.72, 13.57, 13.42, 13.23, 13.08, 12.59, 
    12.43, 12.3, 12.13, 11.98, 11.82, 11.69, 11.53, 11.42, 11.22, 
    11.12, 11.02, 10.82, 10.74, 10.6, 10.48, 10.33, 10.27, 10.15, 
    10.02, 9.91, 9.8, 9.68, 9.56, 9.18, 9.09, 8.87, 8.75, 8.64, 
    8.54, 8.41, 8.32, 8.23, 8.15, 8.08, 7.98, 7.9, 7.8, 7.73, 
    7.65, 7.58, 7.55, 7.45, 7.37, 7.3, 7.27, 7.16, 7.04, 6.98, 
    6.91), No..of.countries = c(6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 
    18L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 
    30L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 47L, 51L, 57L, 61L, 66L, 73L, 76L, 80L, 
    84L, 93L, 94L, 99L, 102L, 105L, 111L, 113L, 120L, 133L, 137L, 
    143L, 146L, 150L, 154L, 161L, 163L, 168L, 169L, 171L, 174L, 
    175L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 177L, 179L, 179L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 
    182L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 
    184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 
    184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 
    186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 
    187L, 187L, 187L, 187L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-188L))
```

**UPDATE**

I got it to look like this now I just have a problem with numbers on Y axis
[Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxrb3.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! instead of adding a image of your data, paste the output from `dput(your_dataset)` here, so we can run code with.

Comment: You have to add the group aes, i.e. `geom_line(aes(group=1))`. The reason is that your month variable is a character. Therefore ggplot2 groups by this variable and you end up with only one point per group and no line shows up.